# Can I instantiate prefabs from an animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have this animation where my character loads up their gun then shoots. I wish there was a way of instantiating the bullet in the animation, instead of having to do that outside of the animation (e.g. in code). I can get around this using one of the following:

1. Add a bullet spawner to the player, which would expose a boolean flag "isBulletRequested". In the animation I can turn this flag on towards the end, and then the bullet spawner knows how to spawn the bullet and reset the flag.
2. Similar to the above, but more generically--add a "prefab spawner" to the player, which has an exposed filed "spawnCommand". It would have values like "spawnCommand=Bullet.prefab (0, -1, 1)", which is asking to instantiate the bullet prefab at the Vector3 position provided.

Even though the solutions above work fine, I don't like them because it's not a smooth workflow; I'll need to create the animation in blender, then have to modify it in Unity to add the spawn. And every time I modify the animation I have to repopulate the spawn commands.

Any thoughts on how to handle this better?

Comment: There are animation events that can be used to trigger code at a specific point in the animation timeline.  [Animation Event](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution that is probably an overkill for cases like this--timelines. With timelines you can add "custom markers" which are parameterized. For example I can create a "prefab spawn marker", that accepts a prefab reference and a position. Now every time I place that marker in the timeline, I can choose which object to spawn.

Here's a video explaining how to mix cutscenes and gameplay: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsEe0_o_934

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html).

Just create a new MonoBehaviour with a Transform variable, which will store the bullet's spawn position. (Parent a new empty GameObject to the Gun, offset properly). When the Animation event is called, instantiate a new Bullet instance at `<variable>.position`.

Comment: It looks like there's no way to give these events parameters, which is not great. But it answers my question I guess.